# PostgreSQL 9.4.11 How to include database ownership and extensions in pg_dump custom compressed dump files?

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I used `pg_dump -Fc ...` to dump my database in a compressed format.

The problem is when I use `pg_restore --create -d [some_auxiliary_db]` to get the database back. **It was restoring it directly to [some_auxiliary_db]** even though in pg_dump / pg_restore documentation pages it was said that:

> -C
>     --create
>   Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to it.
>
> When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html

Also, same thing for the extensions created for my dumped database, they were missing as well.

Whereas, Using a plain-text .sql dump with `pg_dump` includes these info.

**Is there a way or a combination of options that can let me dump in archived format WITH database ownership data AND extensions?**

My pg_dump command:
`pg_dump -Fc -Z1 -U postgres -f [targetdb.dump] [targetdb]`

My pg_restore command:
`pg_restore --create --clean -j 6 -U postgres -d [auxiliarydb] -n public [targetdb.dump]`

Comment: The custom format includes all required info. Show your exact command for pg_restore and pg_dump.

Comment: @jira exact commands added.

Comment: I honestly don't know if this matters or not, but the docs you posted say to use `-C`, but your command line uses `-c`. i.e. upper v.s. lower case difference in the arguments.

Comment: @bill That -Fc outputs a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore... it's for something else.

Comment: I see the same behaviour as you. I also found out that without the '-n' flag for `pg_restore` it behaves as expected. IMHO a bug either in documentation or `pg_restore`.

Comment: When I use -Fc it doesn't output the extension for me, even though one of my tables uses the geometry type.
Could this be an ownership issue?